# Multiple sqlite *.db files for android application

Tags: android, sqlite

What is a best practice to manage different user accounts in one application?
I saw the same topics here but i didn't find answer on my question.
**Is it a best practice to use different "userId-appName.db" for each user in application?**

Or need to add userId in each table?

Answer (score 1):

**No it is not a best practice to use separate databases for each user in the application**.
Use a table with all the users in your application and pass the userId elsewhere. It will eliminate a lot of head ache down the road. and you don't have to track every user's database. Imagine if your app have 10 users in a mobile. How will you track each user's database? another database with all those details?

Comment: I understood. Thank you. But is it possible to open different db when user logging in?
And if yes how to do this? Just provide different names into dbHepler constructor?

Comment: Sorry man i've never tried that. try it for yourself and tell us your experience, for the whole world to know :-)